# Why is it possible to add pd.Timedelta and None?

Tags: python, pandas

The code

```
None + pd.Timedelta("1 day")
```

evaluates to a strange result:

```
Timedelta('-106751 days +00:12:43:145224')
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: That must surely be a bug? It's nearly 300 years so it's not like it goes back towards 1900 somehow. Something overflows?

Comment: Timedelta is assuming None as - infinite and is returning the first time that accept ? :)

Comment: Might wanna look at source code and investigate, `__radd__` for `pd.Timedelta` is defined [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/_libs/tslibs/timedeltas.pyx#L1217)

Comment: it evaluates to NaT for me. pandas version 23.0

Comment: I am really curious to know how None is being interpreted into -106751 days. I converted None to binary and its binary to int and then tried to do some math to get it -106751 days but its binary value is 1315925605 -> x/60 = 21932093/60 = 365534 /24 =  15230. I am drawing at straws but I thought it an interesting test

Comment: @jhourback, did I answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, this behavior has been fixed in later versions of Pandas. From going over the code, it seems to have been fixed for version 0.23 in [this commit](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/commit/21dbe7ac61b2ec5b5248051c80937d59f226c57e).

In a bit more detail - the code for the function that calculates the delta, `_binary_op_method_timedeltalike`, contains the condition:

```
elif other is NaT:  # (N)ot-(A)-(T)ime, the time equivalent of NaN
    return NaT
```

But `None` is not `NaT`, and that's the reason for the bug:

```
>>> None is NaT
False
```

In the later version, a second condition has been added, first converting `other` to a `Timedelta` object, and then testing the condition again, so effectively testing:

```
>>> Timedelta(None) is NaT
True
```

So now `NaT` is returned in the case of `None + Timedelta`.